# Bluemix　phpアプリの httpd 設定方法は？

Tags: php, bluemix

Bluemixでphpのランタイムから、以下のアプリケーションを作成してみました。
http://phptest20151023.mybluemix.net/

この環境に対して、httpdの設定を行いたい場合は、（例えばIP制限をかけようとしてみたのですが）どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

ダッシュボードの「ファイルとログ」から、httpd.confが見えるのですが、編集はできないようで、またsshで環境へのリモート接続を試みたのですが、通らないようでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cloudfoundry/php-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack)を利用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

サンプルアプリケーションとしてphpMyAdminがあり、この中`.bp-config`以下でデフォルトのhttpdの設定を上書きしています。

もしBluemix上でphpMyAdminサンプルを試される場合は、manifest.ymlのdomainを`mybluemix.net`に書換える必要があります。

設定の詳細は [HTTPD, Nginx and PHP configuration](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md#httpd-nginx-and-php-configuration) を参照してみて下さい。